# Starting VM instance 'instance-1' failed. Error: Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 72.0 in region us-central1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to set up a Compute Engine instance on GCP with 96 vCPUs as a test. So I started with the smallest instance possible, prepared my environment for the processing and then edited the instance to this:

```
n1-highcpu-96 (96 vCPUs, 86.4 GB memory)
```

But then, when I started the instance, I got this error:

```
Starting VM instance 'instance-1' failed. Error: Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 72.0 in region us-central1.
```

So, my first question is, is this quota specific to me? Or anyone else who tries the same configuration will face the same error? I'm asking this because I'm using the promotion that GCP provides for new users and I thought this might be a limitation for promotion period.

After doing some research I came across this command to show the quota for different regions:

```
gcloud compute regions describe us-central1
```

And I ran it for the complete list of regions. Some regions were limited to 24 and the maximum number I've got was 72.

```
quotas:
- limit: 72.0
  metric: CPUS
  usage: 0.0
```

So, how can I have an instance with 96 cores?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those limits for vCPUs are the soft limits, the hard limits are specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#available).

To be granted one, you must submit a [quota increase request](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#request_quotas) for the number of vCPUs you want in the location, justifying in the process, why do you need it.

If the request is approved, you will be allowed to run a 96 vCPU GCE instance in the region. Keep in mind that currently, the only exception is the region `southamerica-east1`, in which you can only have up to 64 vCPUs.